# Posting to a lookup field

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, lookup, sharepoint-online

I am trying to post/Create (Not updating) new Item to a LookUp field. I have followed [example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84560/updating-lookup-values-with-the-rest-api), [example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84560/updating-lookup-values-with-the-rest-api) before and succeeded. But for some reason right now I cant make a simple Post call. I need I extra pair of eyes taking a look at my code.

Lookup field internalName is "questionRelation". I now I have to add Id after the name to specify the Id column in the list the Lookup field represents.

```
var data = {
                __metadata: { "type": window._cache.ListItemType },
                Title: user_answer,
                questionRelationId: {
                    'results': parseInt(question_Id)
                }
            };
        var _answers = "answers";
        var _url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + _answers + "')/Items"
        var _type = "POST";
        var _headers = {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
        var _data = JSON.stringify(data);
        jQuery.ajax({

            url: _url,
            type: _type,
            headers: _headers,
            data: _data,
            done: function (data, textStatus, jHXR) {},
            error: function (data, textStatus, jHXR) {});
```

The error I am getting is this:

> An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.

I have set the lookup field to only take one value(id). Input is much appreciated.

> Update

I changed:

```
   questionRelationId: {
                'results': parseInt(question_Id)
            }
```

to:

```
 questionRelationId: parseInt(question_Id)
```

I it worked. they way I did it is when the lookup column takes an array. If it´s a single value you have to remove the `results` object part. wasn´t paying attention when I looked at the docs I provided myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works in my local.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var itemProperties = {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.ChildListItem" },
            "Title": "RestApiCreated",
            "LookupParentId":1
        };

        function createListItem() {

            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('child')/items",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert(data.d.length);
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

And try to use fiddler to monitor the request raw header to identify the header value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir!! I solved it with your help. I updated my question with the solution. I find fiddler a bit owerwhelming. Then again I havn´t set my mind to learn it properly yet. But maybe its about time.